# Python: Does array creation automatically allocate memory?

Tags: python, memory-management

When using large arrays, does python allocate memory as default, unlike C for example?

More specifically, when using the command `array=[1,2,3]`, should I worry about freeing this and every other array I create?

Looking for answers on the web just confused me more.

Comment: Python is garbage collected. You don't need to free memory manually.

Comment: Python has automatic memory-management. It's a much higher-level language than say, C. Also, that is a *list* not an array.

Comment: Python is garbage collected, meaning that memory will be freed once there are no more pointers to the object (i.e. the ref counter drops to zero).  You may "free up" memory if you no longer need a variable that consumes a lot of memory.  You can simply delete it via `del my_variable_name`.  It is more complicated under the hood.  Memory is pre-allocated so that you do not need to recopy the object every time you append an item to a list for example.  Once it goes beyond a threshold, however, it will allocate more memory (e.g. 20%) and recopy the object to this new memory block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array=[1,2,3]` is a list, not an array. It is dynamically allocated (resizes automatically), and you do not have to free up memory.

The same applies to arrays from the `array` module in the standard library, and arrays from the `numpy` library.

As a rule, python handles memory allocation and memory freeing for all its objects; to, maybe, the exception of some objects created using cython, or directly calling c modules.

Comment: and, well, *all objects*.

Comment: Yes, good point; i was typing an edit when you commented. Thank you.